# Can't see value of request headers in firebase?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, http-headers, google-cloud-functions

I do the following:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("bunny", "test");
headers.append("rabbit", "jump");
fetch("blahurl.com/someservice", {headers:headers})
```

On the firebase end:

```
export const listener = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 for (let entry of req.rawHeaders) {
        console.log(entry); // here I see a 'bunny,rabbit' get printed somewhere
    }

     //However this yields undefined:
     req.headers.bunny
```

Not sure how to get the header values, I just have the headers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with cors, so moving the body of the function into it worked, like so:

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const listener = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
```

And then the cookies started appearing correctly...

I'm not entirely sure why though, this isn't a response thing it's just a request.

Answer (score 3):

You should check [Parsing HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests).

You could simply get the request header by this method:

```
req.get('bunny');
req.get('rabbit');
```

Comment: can you capture your request headers and include in your question? (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#headers)

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer while searching for "firebase request header is undefined".

**Problem**

I have written a firebase function (using Node JS) that I am posting to. The post included a header entitled "user_token". In my code, I retrieved the header value like this:

```
const userToken = request.header("user_token");
```

I tested this code on my local machine by using the Firebase CLI server (`firebase serve`) and it worked fine.

However, once I deployed this code (`firebase deploy`) to my Firebase account, I ran into a problem. Posting the exact same header key/value to my Firbase URL, I was getting errors because the `userToken` value was `undefined`.

**Solution**

Ultimately, changing my code to the following solved my problem:

```
const userToken = request.get("x-user-token");
```

@Ben's answer helped point me in the right direction. Initially, I simply changed my code to:

```
const userToken = request.get("user_token");
```

Unfortunately, I still ended up with an undefined userToken value. Looking over the [Parsing HTTP requests documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests), I noticed that their sample header value key began with "x-". Updating my header value key from "user_token" to "x-user-token" did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still has the same problem this is the solution for typscript:

To solve the CORS Problem first:

```
import * as cors from 'cors';
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

export const getmBucksShop = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    corsHandler(request, response, () => {
        //Access Header Values here
        //Your Code Here
    });
});
```

**Does not work**:

```
console.error(request.headers.authorization);
```

**Does Work**:

```
console.error(request.headers['authorization']);
console.error(request.get("authorization"));
```

Required Dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Node docs tell us](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_rawheaders) that rawHeaders is a list of headers, exactly as they were received.

> The keys and values are in the same list. It is not a list of tuples. So, the even-numbered offsets are key values, and the odd-numbered offsets are the associated values.

So any index in this list that is an even number will be the name of a header, and any odd-number index will be a value. This means we can convert the rawHeaders array into a more useful array of key-value pairs like so:

```js
const headers = req.rawRequest.rawHeaders.map((h, i) => {
  // Bail if the index is odd
  if(i%2 !== 0) return false;
  // Create a blank object
  const rtn = {};
  // Add the current rawHeader as the key, 
  // and the next rawHeader as the value
  rtn[h] = req.rawRequest.rawHeaders[i+1];
  return rtn
}).filter(Boolean);
// Filter out the odd values we skipped
```

This will leave us with just an array of key-value pairs like:

```
[
  {
    "header-name": "value"
  }, 
  ...
]
```

If you're just looking for one specific header, you could alternatively use the following:

```js
// Get the index of the specific header we're looking for
const bunnyIndex = req.rawRequest.rawHeaders.findIndex((h) => {
  return h === "bunny";
});
// Get the value by simply adding 1 to the index
const bunny = req.rawRequest.rawHeaders[bunnyIndex + 1];
```