# how to retrieve webhook custom header , sent from dialogflow to cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, api-ai

[how to get myKey header from cloud function?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOX8s.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851528/cant-see-value-of-request-headers-in-firebase?

Comment: Please don't post a screen shot of your code. It makes it very difficult to help you out. Instead, cut and paste the code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is in your first screenshot. Here is the request header:

```
console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
```

just check your logs in Stackdriver and you will see a new field `myKey` in each request.